# What IP will google analytics see for internally hosted site

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

One of our sites that we want to use google analytics on is hosted inside our network.

We would like to exclude the administrators own traffic from the reports, but I am wandering how analytics obtains the users IP address.

If it uses the address which the analytics script is requested from (the HTTP request for the js) then it will see one of our external ips and excluding that will get rid of all traffic.

If it obtains it in javascript once the ga.js is downloaded then it will see the internal 10.x.x.x addresses and filtering out the assigned addresses will have the desired result.

Essentially my question is, will filtering the internal address work or not.

I shall set up an experiment now, but obviously it will take 1 or 2 days before I can be sure about that outcome. If it doesn't work, then I will set custom vars and filter those instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will see the IP that requests the __utm.gif image, then the IP of your internet gateway(s)

You can define a filter to exclude each of your IPs, or your [IP range](https://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55572&hl=en_US&utm_id=ad)

Comment: Yep, confirmed that it is the IP that requests _utm.gif and not a value passed using the javascript